# Delete and Store largest within groupby in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
             userid           watched         timestamp
15           553938              M1           1499371200000
15390        527638              M2           1599731200000
15389        521638              M2           1399901200000
15388        521638              M3           1439841200000
15387        553938              M4           1499521200000
```

For each user, I need to find the 'latest' under `timestamp` column, remove the corresponding row, and store that row in a new dataframe.

One way to do this can be to iterate over all the rows using [DataFrame.iterrows()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and process each row. However, I'm wondering whether there is some more efficient way to perform this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and filter by boolean mask created by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.sort_values('timestamp', ascending=False)
mask = df.duplicated('userid')

df1 = df[mask]
df2 = df[~mask]

print (df1)
       userid watched      timestamp
15     553938      M1  1499371200000
15389  521638      M2  1399901200000

print (df2)
       userid watched      timestamp
15390  527638      M2  1599731200000
15387  553938      M4  1499521200000
15388  521638      M3  1439841200000
```

Or get indices by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), for remove indices use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
idx = df.groupby('userid')['timestamp'].idxmax()

df1 = df.drop(idx)
#alternative
#df1 = df.loc[~df.index.isin(idx)]
df2 = df.loc[idx]

print (df1)
       userid watched      timestamp
15     553938      M1  1499371200000
15389  521638      M2  1399901200000

print (df2)
       userid watched      timestamp
15388  521638      M3  1439841200000
15390  527638      M2  1599731200000
15387  553938      M4  149952120000
```